# Grub not populate my windows ssd

Tags: grub2

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS installed on one ssd and windows 10 installed on another ssd.
My issues are as follows:

1. My grub does not automatically show when i boot up computer; I have to hit the esc key to make  it show up
2. Why doesn't my windows 10 install show up as one of my boot options?

Comment: Are both installs UEFI? Have you run `sudo update-grub`? Grub2's os-prober will not see Windows if hibernated or fast start is on or bitlocker is on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation